# when i hover over bootstrap dropdown's each element does not occupy same background width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a dropdown list. I am not sure what is wrong with the code. When I hover over each list element it does not mark full width in red color.
[here is the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU3TF.png)

Here is my HTML:

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a class="navbar-menu" href="#">Deals</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle navbar-menu-title" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is my CSS:

```css
.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #128C7E;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.navbar-custom a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  background-image: none !important;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hi there,  have just copied your code and it seems to be working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/0244tfgf/

Comment: Have you checked to see if there's some other CSS interfering that could cause it not to work? (use a development tool like firebug to view the applied CSS and see if there's something else thats cascaded down and it preventing the desired action from working).